# Strange TextView Flashing (Links/Paste Disappearing)

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have two basic TextViews in my iOS Application. I don't have much code to them. Basic implementation rules:

```
myUITextView.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
[myUITextView setEditable:YES];
[myUITextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Those are literally the only times that I use `[myUITextView]` in my entire script. That said, whenever a user tries to press and hold to "paste", the paste buttons shows up and quickly disappears. In addition, on my other TextView (same code snippets), when it detects a link, the link flashes from a link blue to a normal grew color quickly.

I was wondering if there were any fixes to these weird behaviors.

Comment: what does this part `[myUITextView becomeFirstResponder];` in your code?

Comment: @aaisataev It makes it so the keyboard comes up at viewDidLoad. Tried removing it and didn't effect anything.